# Best way to simplify this if else statement

Tags: c#

I have the following if else statement. Yes it does the work but any input in making this in a more logical way? Too much repetition with the following field cf.FieldName == "dr"

```
if (loan.CustomFields.Any(cf => cf.FieldName == "dr")) 
{
     var customFieldId = loan.CustomFields.First(cf => cf.FieldName == "dr");
     customFieldId.StringValue = "N";
}
else 
{
     loan.CustomFields.Add(new EncompassRest.Loans.CustomField() 
          {
               FieldName = "dr",
               StringValue = "N"
          });
}
```

Comment: hi, interesting, you could use `FirstOrDefault` to get the item or null, then check if it's null.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `FirstOrDefault` then add the new instance if it's null. The benefit of doing it this way is not having to search through `loan.CustomFields` more than once and the code is much cleaner and easier to read.

```
var fieldName = "dr";
var customFieldId = loan.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(cf => cf.FieldName == fieldName);

if (customFieldId == null)
{
    customFieldId = new EncompassRest.Loans.CustomField() {
        FieldName = fieldName
    };
    loan.CustomFields.Add(customFieldId);
}

customFieldId.StringValue = "N";
```

You're still repeating `fieldName` but at least the "magic value" is only in 1 place in the code.

Answer (score 2):

So your `Any` and `First` can be replaced with a [`FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-5.0):

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
> element is found.

```
var customField = loan.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FieldName == "dr");
if(customField == null)
   loan.CustomFields.Add(customField = CustomField() { FieldName = "dr"});
customField.StringValue = "N";
```

<sub>***Note** : Although concise, I would steer away from this sort of *fancy-pants* side-effect assignment. It's not obvious, which means it's a little easier to make mistakes in the future.*</sub>

Sometimes verbose is better, easier to understand at a glance, and more maintainable:

```
// check for field name
var customField = loan.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(cf => cf.FieldName == "dr");

// if not found create a new custom field and add it
if (customField == null)
{
   customField = CustomField()
   {
      FieldName = fieldName,
      StringValue = "N"
   }
   loan.CustomFields.Add(customField);
}
else
{
   // Found, so lets update the string value
   customField.StringValue = "N"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the most non-repetitive way I can think to do it:

```
var cf =
    loan
        .CustomFields
        .Where(x => x.FieldName == "dr")
        .FirstOrDefault()
        ?? new CustomField() { FieldName = "dr", };

cf.StringValue = "N";

if (!loan.CustomFields.Contains(cf))
{
    loan.CustomFields.Add(cf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is one way

```
var customField = loan.CustomFields.where(x=>x.FieldName.equal("dr")).FirstOrDefault();
if(customField == null) 
    customField = new EncompassRest.Loans.CustomField() 
          {
               FieldName = "dr",
               StringValue = "N"
          });
customField.StringValue = "N";
loan.saveChange();
```

Comment: Should be `Where` but you can drop it and put the lambda in the `FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is good. All you need to do is *extract* your code and give it a nice descriptive name. Only a small optimization of using `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Any` + `First` is recommended. You will get a single line:

```
loan.GetOrAddCustomField("dr").StringValue = "N";
```

Implementation - extension for `Loan` type or you can create a method in a Loan type

```
public static class LoanExtensions
{
    public static CustomField GetOrAddCustomField(this Loan loan, string name)
    {
        var field = loan.CustomFields.FirstOrDefault(f => f.FieldName == name);
        if (field == null)
        {
            field = new CustomField { FieldName = name };
            loan.CustomFields.Add(field);
        }

        return field;
    }
}
```

I would also recommend sticking to [Tell, Don't Ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html#:%7E:text=Tell%2DDon%27t%2DAsk,an%20object%20what%20to%20do.) approach - instead of asking a field from loan and then setting its value you can just tell loan to set field value:

```
loan.SetCustomFieldValue("dr", "N");
```

Implementation is also very straight-forward - it's your code or one-liner

```
public static void SetCustomFieldValue(this Loan loan, string name, string value) =>
   loan.GetOrAddCustomField(name).StringValue = value;
```