# Turning this if else statement into a method

Tags: c#

I have the following logic bellow that I would like to turn into a private method as such.
updatefield(loan, fieldName, value)

```
     if (loan.CustomFields.Any(cf => cf.FieldName == "CX.OS.AO.ORDER")) {
            var customFieldId = loan.CustomFields.First(cf => cf.FieldName == "CX.OS.AO.ORDER");
            customFieldId.StringValue = "N";
        }
        else {
            loan.CustomFields.Add(new EncompassRest.Loans.CustomField() {
                FieldName = "CX.OS.AO.ORDER",
                StringValue = "N"
            });
        }

        if (loan.CustomFields.Any(cf => cf.FieldName == "CX.OS.AO.TRACKINGID")) {
            var customFieldId = loan.CustomFields.First(cf => cf.FieldName == "CX.OS.AO.TRACKINGID");
            customFieldId.StringValue = trackingAppraisal;
        }
        else {
            loan.CustomFields.Add(new EncompassRest.Loans.CustomField() {
                FieldName = "CX.OS.AO.TRACKINGID",
                StringValue = trackingAppraisal
            });
        }
```

Maybe I tried this but not sure if it is the best way.

```
     if (loan.CustomFields.Any(cf => cf.FieldName == "CX.OS.AO.ORDER")) {
            updatefield(loan, fieldName, value) 
        }
        else {
            loan.CustomFields.Add(new EncompassRest.Loans.CustomField() {
                updatefield(loan, fieldName, value) 
            });
        }
```

Comment: If your code is actually working but want a review, this question is for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of StackOverflow

Comment: Could you rephrase your question. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: If you are using visual studio then select the code and go to quick actions -> refactor... Visual studio will suggest a code skelton which can be extracted as a method.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching

Comment: You could use FirstOrDefault instead of checking "any" and if it is default do the if part, if it isn't do the else. that way you could move the whole if/else into the updateField function

Comment: Haven't you asked the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65332602/best-way-to-simplify-this-if-else-statement) already?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have more repeated code you can subsume into `updateField`.  Also, you can use `FirstOrDefault` to output null if not found, saving you the `Any` step.

With a method like this:

```
void updateField (LoanType loan, string fieldName, string value) {

    var customFieldId = loan.CustomFields
        .FirstOrDefault(cf => cf.FieldName == fieldName);

    if (customFieldId != null) 
        customFieldId.StringValue = value;
    else 
        loan.CustomFields.Add(new EncompassRest.Loans.CustomField() {
            FieldName = fieldName,
            StringValue = value
        });

}
```

You could do this:

```
updateField(loan, "CX.OS.AO.ORDER", "N");
updateField(loan, "CX.OS.AO.TRACKINGID", trackingAppraisal);
```

And furthermore, if 'loan' is a field/property the same class, then you can avoid even passing that in as a parameter as it would already be in scope of `updateField`.